# How can I vertically align an equals sign in a tikz node?

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, vertical-alignment, boxes, relation-symbols

I want to align an equals sign in a tikz node like in the third node of this picture:

[image: equals sign nodes]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newlength\eqheight
\settoheight\eqheight{$=$}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={minimum height=1em,rectangle,draw}]
    \node at (0, 0) {$=$};
    \node at (1, 0) {$A=$};
    \node at (2, 0) {\raisebox{0pt}[\eqheight][0pt]{\raisebox{-1pt}{$=$}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In the first node the equals sign is not vertically aligned correctly, because its box has more space at the bottom than at the top.

When you add the character "A", the box is higher and thus the equals sign will be aligned correctly.

In the third node I manually raise the box by `-1pt`, but I don't want to "hard code" the `-1pt`.

I tried to get the `-1pt` by using `\settodepth` to get the depth of the equals sign but that appears to be 0. Is there a way to align it correctly without "hard coding" the value?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! There is no way around manual adjustment. The reason is that TeX can't look into the box of the character, but just knows its height, width, and depth. And the height of `=` is measured from the baseline, including white space below the sign itself. Tex doesn't know whether the stuff inside the box extends to its borders or not; for TeX there is no difference between '=' and `o`, even though the first has lots of white space, whereas the second even overshoots its box.

Comment: @gernot good to know, thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two issues:

- The text nodes should be centered at their base lines (or math axis lines).
- Equal space above and below the symbols.

The first issue can be solved by anchoring the nodes at their base lines.
The second issue is trickier, because TeX does *not* know, where the black
pixels of a glyph are. It does only know the nominal glyph bounding box:

> [image: Glyph bounding boxes]

Created with:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{color}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{.2pt}
\begin{document}
\def\x#1{%
  \textcolor{red}{%
    \fbox{%
      $\color{black}#1$%
    }%
  }%
}
$\x{=}\;\x{A}$
\end{document}
```

The glyph bounding box always includes the base line. Symbols above the base line have additional space below to the base line, symbols above the base line as the underscore have additional space above.

The equals sign is centered around the math axis. This can be used to calculate the white space:

First, the symbol is moved to the base line. Then the height of the symbol is half its net height. Because of the symbol's symmetry, the depth has the same amount as the height.

Then, TikZ gets this symbol and can draw a symmetric border.

Finally, the former shift needs to be revered by moving the node up by the amount of the math axis.

Example file:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every node/.style={
    rectangle,
    anchor=base,
    draw,
  }]
    \pgfmathsetmacro\MathAxis{height("$\vcenter{}$")}
    \node (a) at (0, \MathAxis pt) {%
      \sbox0{$=$}%
      \sbox0{\raisebox{-\MathAxis pt}{\usebox0}}% Equals sign at base line
      \dp0=\ht0 % The equals sign is symmetric
      \usebox0%
    };
    \node (b) at (1, 0) {$A=$};

    % Red line at math axis
    \draw[thin, red, yshift=\MathAxis, opacity=.5]
    (a.west |- 0, 0) -- (b.east |- 0, 0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

## Symbol `Join` of package `wasysym`

There are two problems with the `\Join` symbol of package `wasysym`:

- The reported glyph bounding box has a wrong height (seems to be a bug).
- It is *not* vertically centered at the math axis but at the upper bar of the
  equals sign. Maybe, the font designer wanted to avoid that the symbol descends
  the base line.

The font for the equals sign is `cmr10.pfb`, the font for the symbol `\Join` of package `wasysym` is `wasy10.pfb`. Both fonts have the same em size of 1000
and the same math axis is at 250. The height of the `\Join` glyph is 637 and
its center is at 342 and the depth is -47 (above the baseline). These values can be looked up in [FontForge](https://fontforge.github.io/en-US/), for example.

Then the formula for the shift is:

```
<math axis in TeX> * <symbol center in glyph units> / <math axis in glyph units>
= <math axis in TeX> * 347 / 250
```

The half height of the symmetric symbol is:

```
<math axis in TeX units> * (<height in glyph units> - <center in glyph units>) / <math axis in glyph units>
= <math axis in TeX> * (637 - 342) / 250
= <math axis in TeX> * 295 / 250
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every node/.style={
    rectangle,
    anchor=base,
    draw,
  }]
    \pgfmathsetmacro\MathAxis{height("$\vcenter{}$")}
    \edef\JoinShift{\the\dimexpr\MathAxis pt * 347 / 250}
    \node (a) at (0, \JoinShift) {%
      \sbox0{\raisebox{-\JoinShift}{$\Join$}}%
      \dp0=\dimexpr\MathAxis pt * 295 / 250\relax
      \ht0=\dp0 %
      \usebox0%
    };
    \node (b) at (1, 0) {$A=\Join$};

    % Red line at math axis
    \draw[thin, red, yshift=\MathAxis, opacity=.5]
    (a.west |- 0, 0) -- (b.east |- 0, 0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result \Join]

Comment: As you can see in your picture, this doesn't help with aligning within the node at all.

Comment: @MoritzS. I had aligned the vertical position of the equal signs across the nodes. The updated answer also takes care for symmetric inner margins of the left node.

Comment: This works now for the equals sign. I also tried it with `\Join` from the `wasysym` package but that doesn't work. `\fbox{$\Join$}` with 0pt fboxsep looks like [this](http://i.imgur.com/CapiVEm.png). Is this a bug in the `wasysym` package?

Comment: @MoritzS. The symbol `\Join` requires more work, see updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add a `\vphantom`.

[image: vphantom]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newlength\eqheight
\settoheight\eqheight{$=$}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={minimum height=1em,rectangle,draw}]
    \node at (0, 0) {\vphantom{A}$=$};
    \node at (1, 0) {$A=$};
    \node at (2, 0) {\raisebox{0pt}[\eqheight][0pt]{\raisebox{-1pt}{$=$}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: But then the box for the equals sign gets so large. I'd prefer to use the size of the original box.